# Cannot save a record in the Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So to get a record in the User model I run

```
 @user = User.find(1)
```

Then to change an attribute:

```
 @user.active = false
```

It then returns false

When I run

```
 @user.save
```

I get

```
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.3ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE (LOWER(`users`.`username`) = LOWER('sean') AND `users`.`id` != 1) LIMIT 1
(0.3ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE (LOWER(`users`.`email`) = LOWER('sean@gmail.com') AND `users`.`id` != 1) LIMIT 1
(0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
 => false
```

Comment: Try `@user.save` then check `@user.errors` to see if there are any validation errors on save.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this to see if errors are being thrown

```
@user.save!
```

If your `@user.save` is returning false then it means there's an error and something is preventing it from being saved. You can use `@user.errors` at that point to see what the errors are.

Comment: It was a password length validation error that was coming up.  I changed it to include :on => :create, :update

Comment: Actually, It won't work if I have :on => :update.  The console asks for a min length password.  Any Advice?

Comment: It seems you added a validation to password AFTER your user already was in the database. You have two options 1) remove the password length validation or 2) update the user password so it meets validation. I'd go with #2. Just do `@user.password = 'somevalidpassword'` and then try saving.

Comment: I deleted the database and made a new one and new user.  But still the problem remains.  If I have :on => :update for the password validation.  It will want a password for any attribute update it seems.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. Doing this managed to solve it:

```
@user.save(validate: false)
```

Here is the link to original answer:
[How to skip validations as admin during update_attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031787/how-to-skip-validations-as-admin-during-update-attributes/14032020#14032020)